# how can i get a field on a mysql table?

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

Im a php/mySQL newbie and am trying to get the hang of it. I have code to detect whether i get a username/password match, and now im trying to get the userid field so i can update the record. Heres what I have so far:

```
    $sql = "SELECT username FROM users WHERE username='$username' AND password='$password'";
    $result = $link->query($sql) or die(mysqli_error());
```

Using print_r($result) shows that there is an item, but im lost from here on out.

Comment: You say "userid" in your question but in your example you say "username", which is it? Also, make sure you are escaping $username and $password.

Comment: im trying to get the userid which is my primary key. The objective is to update a field sessionid in that record, if you dont think im going about that the right way feel free to correct me.

Comment: You need to fetch a row from `$result` with `$result->fetch_assoc()`

Comment: http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.fetch-assoc.php

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this.

```
$sql = "SELECT username FROM users WHERE username='$username' AND password='$password'";
$result = $link->query($sql) or die(mysqli_error());

while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result, MYSQLI_ASSOC)) {

        $userID= $row['username'] ;
        // If you need other field as userID just change the sql and the index of $row according to that.

}
```

EDIT

If you want to get only one row.

```
if($result->num_rows==1)
{
   $row = $result->fetch_array(MYSQLI_ASSOC);
   $userID = $row["username"];
}
```

Comment: Typo in this example, you use $res when you should use $result.

Comment: great answer, for the upvote, if theres only 1 object i need (like in this case) do I need to use a while loop?

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps this will help.  In *any* programming language, running an SQL query is going to consist of these steps:

1. Build the text of the SQL statement that you want to run.
2. *(Optional)* If your statement involves the use of **parameters** (or "placeholders"), prepare an array of the parameter-values that are to be substituted for each of them.
3. ("Prepare" and...) "Run" the query, on some previously-opened "database connection."  (In your example, "$link" must correspond to that connection.)  This gives you a *handle* (you called it "$result") that corresponds to the zero-or-more rows that were returned by that query.
4. Now, use that handle to retrieve each of these rows, one at a time, until there are no more or until you're tired of doing it.
5. *(Optional)* Be neat and tidy and "close" the handle, thus indicating to the database system that it can discard all of the resources it was using to furnish those rows to you.

"Those, in simple terms, are the basic steps that *every* program in the known universe are going to go through," and if you now browse again through the PHP documentation, you'll see that there are functions that correspond to each of these steps.  Browse through the chapters you've been reading and see if you can now match the up to the scenario I just described.  HTH...